# Symfony get all requests to safely kill sessions

Tags: php, symfony, session

I need to plan maintenance to a Symfony 2.8 based SaaS. Some requests might involve complex DB change (several updates on several tables), so it would definitely not be nice to kill sessions straight away (I might check if the user is authenticated several times during the same request).

I'd like to get all sessions for which no request is pending (and kill them). For these users impede logging in again, and for the few users who were "caught" during a request re-run the same process until all requests are over.

Comment: not sure its a good idea but deleting the local session files should work

Comment: It does not solve the mid request problem :-(

Comment: stop apache, delete session files